Can any non-empty open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ be written as a countable union of open balls whose centres belong to the open set itself?
Consider an arbitrary non-empty open set $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$. Is it true that one can find a countable collection of open balls $(B(x_l,r_l))_{l \in \mathbb N}$, where $x_l \in \Omega$ and $r_l > 0$ for every $l \in \mathbb N$, such that
$$ \Omega = \bigcup_{l=1}^\infty B(x_l,r_l) \qquad ? $$
If this is true, this statement essentially tells us that any non-empty open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ can be written as a countable union of open balls, each centred at some element of $\Omega$.
I've seen this fact being used in some answers in MSE but, unfortunately, I can't really precise exactly in which answers, which means that I am unable to ask the answerers directly. Therefore, I've decided to create a post for this question.
Now, if I recall correctly, most of the times this property is justified through the second-countability of $\mathbb R^n$, but I can't make sense out of this. Does this has anything to do with the fact that every open set in $\mathbb R^n$ is a union of open balls whose centres have rational coordinates and whose radii are rational ?
Thanks for any help in advance.

It is possible. Also note that if the centers (centra?) weren’t in $\Omega$ then the union of those balls wouldn’t be $\Omega$.

Yes, this can be stated slightly stronger as "$\mathbb R^n$ has a countable basis of open balls."

Thanks for your comments. @ThomasAndrews So, this is indeed a consequence of $\mathbb R^n$ being second-countable, correct?

@BenSteffan that's not what second countable says. It neither talks about balls, rational centers or rational radii.

@freakish Fine. I'll amend to "A common proof of the secound-countability of $\mathbb{R}^n$ shows that the set of all balls with rational center and radius forms a (countable) basis of the topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$."

Well, being second countable isn't enough - you need the basis elements to be balls.

In a second countable space, every union of open balls is a countable union of open balls. So knowing the space is second countable makes it a little easier to show that every open set is a countable union of open balls, you don't have to worry about "countable".

Let $X:=\Omega\cap\Bbb Q^n$ and for every $x\in X$, $R_x:=\{r\in\Bbb Q^+\mid B(x,r)\subset\Omega\}$. Then,
$$\Omega=\bigcup_{x\in X,\ r\in R_x}B(x,r).$$
$\supseteq$ is obvious, and for $\subseteq$, you may use the fact that if $d(y,x)<r\le R/2$, then $B(x,r)\subseteq B(y,R)$.
